# Javascript if statement and && operator not working when using twice same variable

Tags: javascript

In the following code, it looks if the time is below 8:30 AM. It's working fine (tested when time was 2:26 AM):

```
function workingSchedule() {
    var h = new Date().getHours();
    var m = new Date().getMinutes();
    if (h < 8 && m < 30) {
        window.alert("Sorry, we're not working at these hours.");
    }
}
```

However, if I want the code to check if 1) it's earlier than 8:30AM; 2) it's later than 12:00 midday, it won't work.

```
function workingSchedule() {
    var h = new Date().getHours();
    var m = new Date().getMinutes();
    if ((h < 8 && m < 30) && h > 12) {
        window.alert("Sorry, we're not working at these hours.");
    }
}
```

Basically, I have a working schedule from 8:30 AM to 12:00, and from 2:00 PM to 5:00 PM. I want to display the alert window text "*Sorry, we're not working at these hours*" whenever the time of the machine (computer, laptop, cellphone) is **not** between these hours.

Is it a problem with `&&` operators, or with `if` statement, or both?

Comment: How can `h` less than 8 **AND** `h` greater than 12?

Comment: That moment when you realize you've made such dumb thing. That's what happens when you program non-stop. Thank you all.

Comment: @alej27: It's more than the `||`/`&&` thing, though; I've flagged up the other issues in my answer.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder also a moment you realize that it is not as simple as it looks either :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to check if it's before 8:30 **or** after noon, not **and** after noon. That's `||`, not `&&`.

> Basically, I have a working schedule from 8:30 AM to 12:00, and from 2:00 PM to 5:00 PM.

Your current code checks to see if it's after 1 p.m. ("hour greater than 12"), not if it's after noon. It also doesn't handle the 2-5 shift.

So, see comments:

```
if (h < 8 ||                  // It's before 8 a.m.
    (h === 8 && m < 30) ||    // It's 8:00-8:29 a.m.
    (h >= 12 && h < 14) ||    // It's 12:00-1:59 p.m.
    h >= 17                   // It's 5 p.m. or later
   ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You asked if `h < 8` *and* `h > 12` at the same time. Obviously, this can never be true.

It is very likely you intended to use an or instead:

```
(h < 8 && m < 30) || h > 12
```

Have a look over javascript's [list of logical operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators), but know that

> `expr1 || expr2`Returns `expr1` if it can be converted to true; otherwise, returns `expr2`. Thus, when used with Boolean values, ***|| returns true if either operand is true.***